# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: antlr/ANTLRException

Tags: sql, database, spring, hql

I am trying to update a value from database . but i dont know why this error is coming.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: antlr/ANTLRException
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.createQueryTranslator(ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.java:35)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:74)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:56)
```

DetailsDaoImpl.java

```
@Override
public boolean updateUserProfile(String name, String displayname) {
    String profileUpdateQuery="UPDATE demo.updateprofile SET displayname='"+ displayname+"' WHERE userId=:userId";
    System.out.println("query is"+profileUpdateQuery);
    Query updateQuery=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(profileUpdateQuery);
    System.out.println(updateQuery+"-----");
    updateQuery.setParameter("userId", name);
    int resultOfUpdate=updateQuery.executeUpdate();
    System.out.println(resultOfUpdate);
    return resultOfUpdate>0?true:false;
}
```

console

```
query isUPDATE demo.updateprofile SET displayname='xyz' WHERE userId=:userId
```

Comment: Clean and recompile your codeand Try again.. Generally occurs when `.class` file  is not present while running.

Comment: Which version of hibernate r u using?